# How to CREATE TABLE with disjoint relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, relationships

I am trying to create a table using a `disjoint subtype relationship`.

For example, if the `Supertype` is furniture, and I have 3 `Subtypes` of furniture: chair, couch, and table.

Then:

```
CREATE TABLE Furniture
(order_num NUMBER(15), desc VARCHAR2(20), type VARCHAR2(10));
```

How do I make an option to pick type of chair, couch or table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database

Comment: FWIW, [Oracle has objects](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjint.htm) supporting inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use REFERENCES in the CREATE TABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE Furniture_SubTypes
(
    sub_type     VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO Furniture_SubTypes VALUES ('Chair');
INSERT INTO Furniture_SubTypes VALUES ('Couch');
INSERT INTO Furniture_SubTypes VALUES ('Table');

CREATE TABLE Furniture
(
    order_num    NUMBER,
    description  VARCHAR(20),
    sub_type     REFERENCES Furniture_SubTypes(sub_type)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Furniture (
    order_num NUMBER(15),
    description VARCHAR2(20),
    type VARCHAR2(10),
    check (type in ('chair', 'couch', 'table'))
);
```

Note that `desc` is a poor choice for a column name, because it is a keyword in SQL (used for `order by`).

Comment: One last question. Each type of furniture has its own attributes. e.g. Chair has attributes of legs, color. Couch has attributes of fabric. etc.

Would i create separate tables for each type of furniture?

Comment: That is a very different question.  In some cases yes, and in some cases no.  If you want a more detailed answer, you should ask another question, with more information about the attributes and how you will use the tables.